# know whether parent image view is covered with child image view or not

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Image 1:**
[image]

**Image 2:**
[image]

I have been working on this since today morning but didn't find any luck. I have two image views in one UIView. Parent view (Gray colored image) should fully covered with the child view (red colored image). In case if the parent view not fully covered with the child view I have to prompt an alert. The user can rotate,scale the child image. I have tried these methods like `CGRectIntersectsRect(frame1, frame2),CGRectContainsRect` but no luck. Thank you for your time and any suggestions are very valuable

Answer (score 1):

If you are not manipulating the bounds of the parent:

```
(CGPointEqualToPoint(childView.frame.origin, CGPointMake(0, 0)) &&
CGSizeEqualToSize(childView.frame.size, parentView.frame.size))
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot say there is an option of rotate,scale to child view